# How do I dynamically change Manipulate controls?

Tags: manipulate

What I'd like to be able to do is dynamically change the axis of a 3D plot inside a manipulate.

For example if I have a function that has three input variables I'd like a 3D plot using 2 of the input variables and be able to manipulate the third. The part that I've had trouble with is making the axis of the plots dynamic.

This is how far I've got:

```
axes = {{x, 0, 10}, {y, 0, 10}, {z, 0, 10}};
Manipulate[
Plot3D[fun1[x, y, z], {x, 0, 10}, {y, 0, 10}], {z, 0, 
10}, {{axis1, x, "Axis 1"}, axes[[All, 1]], 
PopupMenu}, {{axis2, y, "Axis 2"}, axes[[All, 1]], PopupMenu}]
```

which gives me

[image: result]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

To be more clear;

The axes I would like to change are the x and y axis on the 3d plot. What I'd like to be able to do is select axis 1 = x and axis 2 = z and have the manipulate change to y.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) [`Read the FAQs`](http://tinyurl.com/cacvex2)!  3) When you see good Q&A, vote them up by [`clicking the gray triangles`](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.  ALSO, remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [`by clicking the checkmark sign`](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
fun1[x_, y_, z_] := (x - 1) (y - 2) (z - 3);
h[u_, n_] := Complement[{x, y, z}, {u}][[n]]

Manipulate[
 Plot3D[fun1[x, y, z] /. m -> m1 /. h[m, 1] -> x /. h[m, 2] -> y, {x, 0, 10}, {y, 0, 10}, 
        Evaluated -> True, AxesLabel -> {Style[h[m, 1], Large, Bold, Red], 
                                         Style[h[m, 2], Large, Bold, Red]}],
 Row[{Control[{{m, z, "Manip"}, {x, y, z}, PopupMenu}],
      Control[{{m1, 0,}, 0, 10}]}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]
[image: Mathematica graphics]
[image: Mathematica graphics]
[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Edit**

Perhaps this is safer

```
fun1[x_, y_, z_] := (x - 1) (y - 2) (z - 3);
h[a_, n_] := Complement[{u, v, w}, Position[{x, y, z}, a][[1]]][[n]]

Manipulate[
 Plot3D[fun1[x, y, z] /. m -> m1 /. {x -> u, y -> v, z -> w} /. h[m, 1] -> x /. h[m, 2] ->y, 
       {x, 0, 10}, {y, 0, 10}, Evaluated -> True, 
  AxesLabel -> {Style[h[m, 1], Large, Bold, Red], Style[h[m, 2], Large, Bold, Red]}], 
 Row[{Control[{{m, z, "Manip"}, {x, y, z}, PopupMenu}], 
     Control[{{m1, 0,}, 0, 10}]}]]
```

Comment: Much appreciated belisarius. I think that's what I'm after.

Comment: I was thinking of something like this where you select the two axes and manipulate the one that's left;              Manipulate[
 Plot3D[fun1[x, y, m3] /. {m1 -> x, m2 -> y}, {x, 0, 10}, {y, 0, 10}, 
  Evaluated -> True, 
  AxesLabel -> {Style[m1, Large, Bold, Red], 
    Style[m2, Large, Bold, Red]}, 
  PlotRange -> {-100, 100}], {{m1, x, "Axis 1"}, 
  Complement[{x, y, z}, {m2}], PopupMenu}, {{m2, y, "Axis 2"}, 
  Complement[{x, y, z}, {m1}], 
  PopupMenu}, {{m3, 5, Dynamic[Complement[{x, y, z}, {m1, m2}][[1]]]},
   0, 10}]

Comment: @Cam Selecting only for manipulating it seems the same thing to me

Comment: Yes belisarius in this example that is true. What I want to do ultimately though is have 10 or so inputs, select the x/y axes and have all the others as manipulate controls. Thanks for your help, you've pointed me in the right direction.

Comment: Cam, were you able to build "have 10 or so inputs, select the x/y axes and have all the others as manipulate controls"?