# Manipulate for variable number of sliders

Tags: plotting, manipulate

I'm trying to use Manipulate for plotting multidimensional data, where higher dimensions are defined as sliders.

First, this simple example works:

```
myfun[v1_Real, v2_Real, v3_Real, v4_Real, v5_Real] := 
 Sin[v1]*Cos[v2]*v3 + v4*v5

Manipulate[
 Plot3D[myfun[v1, v2, v3, v4, v5], {v1, 0, 2}, {v3, 0, 2}], {{v5, 
   0.5}, 0., 1.}, {{v2, 0.5}, 0., 1.},(*{{v3,0.5},0.,1.},*){{v4, 0.5},
   0., 1.}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But when the dimensions for plotting and for controls are configured to change dynamically, then Mathematica gets stuck:

```
Manipulate[
 With[{myaxis = Sequence @@ {{v[ax1], 0, 2}, {v[ax2], 0, 2}}, 
   mycontrols = 
    Sequence @@ {{{v[sl1], 0.5}, 0., 1.}, {{v[sl2], 0.5}, 0., 
       1.}, {{v[sl3], 0.5}, 0., 1.}}}, 
  Manipulate[Plot3D[myfun[v[1], v[2], v[3], v[4], v[5]], myaxis], 
   mycontrols]], {ax1, Range[1, 4, 1], ControlType -> Setter}, {ax2, 
  Range[ax1 + 1, 5, 1], ControlType -> Setter}, {sl1, 
  Complement[Range@5, {ax1, ax2}], ControlType -> Setter}, {sl2, 
  Complement[Range@5, {ax1, ax2, sl1}], ControlType -> Setter}, {sl3, 
  Complement[Range@5, {ax1, ax2, sl1, sl2}], ControlType -> Setter}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

How can I make the last piece of code to evaluate correctly?

Comment: [Related Q/A](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1199/125)?

Comment: I used similar example [Nesting Manipulate](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/AdvancedManipulateFunctionality.html), but my problem is not covered in these toturials

Comment: Also [relevant](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/40912/134) ?

Comment: b.gatessucks, this thread is related, but not tested with sliders for variables not used for axes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't quite what you asked, but it is hopefully giving the required result.  The whole nested `Manipulate` with changing controls seemed like a can of worms to me.

```
Manipulate[
 If[oldax1 != ax1 || oldax2 != ax2,
  If[ax1 == ax2, ax2 = Mod[ax1, 5] + 1];
  oldax1 = ax1; oldax2 = ax2;
  set[ax1, ax2]];
 Plot3D[f[{a, b, c, v1, v2}], {v1, 0, 2}, {v2, 0, 2}],

 {{ax1, 1, ""}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}}, {{oldax1, 1}, None},
 {{ax2, 2, ""}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}}, {{oldax2, 1}, None},
 {{a, 0.5}, 0., 1.}, {{b, 0.5}, 0., 1.}, {{c, 0.5}, 0., 1.},
 {{sl1, 3}, None}, {{sl2, 3}, None}, {{sl3, 3}, None},
 Dynamic@f[{a, b, c, v1, v2}],
 Initialization -> {
   Clear[set, f];
   set[a1_, a2_] :=
     (ax1 = a1; ax2 = a2;
      With[{other = Complement[Range@5, {ax1, ax2}]}, 
       sl1 = other[[1]]; sl2 = other[[2]]; sl3 = other[[3]]];
      f[v_] := myfun[Permute[v, {sl1, sl2, sl3, ax1, ax2}]]
      );
   }]
```

[image: 1]

There is no longer any changing controls, instead we just select which of the variables we plot against.  These are fed into `myfun` by permuting the order of the variables (now passed a list instead of a sequence).

There are a few other tricks in here, which I might explain later if there is any interest.

Comment: That's a nice answer! +1

Comment: I commented out Dynamic@f[{a, b, c, v1, v2}], because it shows the long expression within the function

Comment: one problem with this approach is that you mess up values of variables when dimensions switch from sliders to axes

Comment: @denfromufa I'm not sure what you mean by that.  Can you explain further?